# How to take data and compare?

Tags: excel

I want to determine 3 results whether it's above or below school average in function form. Like if GPA is negative then the output would be "below", "positive" then above average. Also comparing all 3 results for whose has the best gpa.

**Example**

1. John's GPA compared to his school average is *0.38* standard deviation *above* the school average.
2. Josh's GPA compared to his school average is *0.25* standard deviation *above* the school average.
3. Jake's GPA compared to his school average is *-2* standard deviation *below* the school average.

What function can I use to determine the "above" or "below" text form results?

Comment: @KenWhite How can I determine whether is negative or positive. I tried using if function for that it doesn't seem to work for that.

Comment: You use the `>` operator, as usual. `=IF(GPA > Avg, "Above", "Below")`. To use three values you nest the `IF()` calls, like `=IF(GPA > Avg, "Greater", IF(GPA = Avg, "Equal", "Less"))`. Did you try reading the documentation for `IF()`?

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you I finally understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare two values, use `IF()`:

```
=IF(A > B, "Greater", "Less")
```

To compare three, nest the calls to `IF()`:

```
=IF(GPA = Avg, "Equal", IF(GPA > Avg, "Above", "Below"))
```